# Retrieve data from mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I've got a mongodb database and I want to retrieve data from java mongodb API. My database is like the following json:

```
{
   "_id": 123456,
    "value": {
              "count": 123,
              "persons": 456
             }
}
```

I want to perform queries for specific id in order to get count and persons. My code is:

```
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", no);
            DBCursor  cursor = coll_in.find(query);
            System.out.println(cursor);
```

I found the object in database with find(query) and I want to retrieve count value and persons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cursor what you are getting from DB with `coll_in.find(query)` can be a set of documents or you need to use `*.findOne()` or with your variant do like this:

```
try (DBCursor cursor = coll_in.find(query)) {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                final DBObject result = cursor.next();
                Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) result.get("value");
                System.out.println(value.get("count"));
                System.out.println(value.get("persons"));
            }
        } catch (final MongoException ex) {
            // error
        }
```

But to minimize your code use `findOne()` if you sure that you have unique _id.

Comment: I want to do so for specific ids not all ids in database.

Comment: That is ok. You already getting your query result in `cursor`. You need loop through `cursor` even if it contains only one document like in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Example for findOne() method

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", no);
DBObject object = coll_in.findOne(query);
Map<String, Object> doc = (Map<String, Object>) object;
if(doc != null) {
    Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) doc.get("value");

    System.out.println(value.get("count"));
    System.out.println(value.get("persons"));
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at twitter4j.examples.tweets.UpdateStatus.main(UpdateStatus.java:108)
Java Result: 1

Comment: check `doc` object before use it.

Comment: For `.findOne(DBObject)` its better to send like parameter `DBObject` where you need specify query.